# Methanol/Ethanol (other alcohol) based life-form and its planet?

Tags: planets, physics, science-fiction, chemistry, xenobiology

This is the second part of my [first question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/37164/methanol-ethanol-other-alcohol-based-life-form-aliens), where I've asked about an alien-civilization which uses methanol/ethanol/other alcohol as a solvent instead of water.

In this question, I'm more interested in the environment of the planet, its atmosphere, oceans, etc.

How would such a planet work?

Thanks for all your ideas!

Comment: In its current form, this question is waaay too broad. I would recommend splitting this up into 3 or 4 individual questions. also, are you asking if water on the planet is replaced with methanol or ethanol?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is kind of unclear, so I'm assuming you want to replace the water in the ocean with methanol?

For one, methanol is toxic to most organisms. So for a start, humans and most other intelligent life forms would not exist, as we would not have a fresh safe drinking water supply. That eliminates most, if not all fish and other sea animals, which basically just leaves us with plants. According to [this website](http://www.ehow.com/info_8006187_effect-alcohol-plants.html),

> Methanol is the simplest alcohol. It is often used as a racing fuel and as a solvent. Studies have shown that methanol actually stimulates the growth of many cultivated plants. Methanol is used by the plant's metabolism in the same way the plant uses carbon dioxide. A solution of 30 percent methanol seems to be most effective in increasing plant yield.

It says that methanol would help stimulate the growth of many plants, but they would still need a moderate amount of water to photosynthesize and survive.

TLDR: No plants, animals or humans, other than extremely hardy prokaryotes.